# How to take the absolute value using awk?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

If I have below two dates:

```
2015-09-12,2015-08-13
```

And I need to get the number of days between them, I will use the below code:

```
awk -F'[-,]' '{print 360*($4-$1)+30*($5-$2)+($6-$3)}'
```

The output for this code will be `-29` while actually the difference is `29`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can define functions in  `awk` like:

```
awk -F'[-,]' '
  function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
  {print abs(360*($4-$1)+30*($5-$2)+($6-$3))}'
```

Or:

```
  function abs(v) {v += 0; return v < 0 ? -v : v}
```

For the returned value to be converted to its canonical form for both negative and positive numbers and strings to always be converted to numbers. Without it, `abs($0)` where the input record is `1e2` would yield `1e2`, while for `-1e2`, it would yield `-100`.

Answer (score 21):

The common trick for this kind of situations is to use square root of the square:

```
awk -F'[-,]' '{print sqrt((360*($4-$1)+30*($5-$2)+($6-$3))^2)}'
```

Comment: A bit overkill though. Note that `sqrt(x^2)` is fine, but `sqrt(x)^2` can introduce tiny errors that  can cause surprises. For busybox `awk`, it needs to be build with math support enabled (not the default in Debian packages for instance).

Comment: Wouldn't sqrt(x)^2 simply fail for negative numbers?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury That's why it is `sqrt(x^2)`.

Comment: @jimmij: I'm replying to the comment on your answer, not to the answer itself.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220588/how-to-take-the-absolute-value-using-awk/220594?noredirect=1#comment899347_220594) is missing the point of [Stéphane's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220588/how-to-take-the-absolute-value-using-awk#comment611364_220594) about doing `sqrt(x)^2` in general. What that'd do with negative x is irrelevant.

Comment: @EdMorton You wouldn't write ever write sqrt(x)^2 anyway because it's useless -- it returns x (possibly with some rounding error) for nonnegative x, and -nan for negative x.  So there is a much more compelling reason not to use that as an absolute value than potential rounding errors.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
awk -F'[-,]' '{d=360*($4-$1)+30*($5-$2)+($6-$3);print (d>0)?d:-d}'
```

Comment: This is probably the most efficient (performance) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're on GNU `awk`, the funky `mktime` function comes in useful here.

```
awk -F, '{ gsub(/-/," ",$0);a=(mktime($2 " 23 59 59")-mktime($1 " 00 00 00"))/86400;print a*(a<0?-1:1)}' file.txt
29
```