# AWK usage for simulatenous inline division and taking absolute value

Tags: shell-script, awk, syntax

I have a data file of this format (top row is for reference):

```
    E          T               N         D                 S             s                 R          k
   0.45847  300.0000      9.99979156  0.44254427E+02  0.49221658E-04  0.98763353E+19  0.73239256E-09  0.24892539E+15
   0.45947  300.0000      9.97603847  0.51763106E+02 -0.24189016E-04  0.97909193E+19 -0.24467623E-08  0.23855274E+15
```

Now I need to generate a file in the same column format containing these:

```
N         (k/(s/300.0000))         Abs(S)/E         exp(Abs(S)/E)
```

In short, I first need to divide the two columns and take the absolute value of Column(5) and again perform the exponentiation.

I am using the code:

```
while read -a line; do echo -e " ${line[2]}\t" `awk "BEGIN {print ${line[7]}/${line[5]}/300}"` ; done < filename
```

But this only gets me to the 2nd column. CI need to take the absolute value as in the next two columns?

I have come till:

```
 while read -a line; do echo -e ${line[4]} | awk ' { if($line[4]>=0 ) {print $line[4] } else {print $line[4]*(-1)} }'; done <
```

But I can't combine this with the last column-wise division code. Am I missing some syntax with `BEGIN` or `END` usage in `awk`?
Also the result comes out messed up in decimal format. A

P.S.: Is `awk` the right tool to do this? Shall I try `python` or something? I know I can't use spreadsheets as I will have over 2 dozens of these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `awk` is correct tool as you could do:

```
$ awk 'function abs(x) {return x<0 ? -x : x}
     NR>1{printf ("%e %e %e %e\n", $3, $NF/($6/300.0000), abs($5)/$1, exp(abs($5)/$1) );
}' infile

9.999792e+00 7.561268e-03 1.073607e-04 1.000107e+00
9.976038e+00 7.309408e-03 5.264547e-05 1.000053e+00
```

You can simulate abs() function as like above, or use a Ternary Operator to generate it like as following without defining a function:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{ $5*=($5<0?-1:1);
    printf("%e %e %e %e\n", $3, $NF/($6/300.0000), $5/$1, exp($5/$1) )}' infile
9.999792e+00 7.561268e-03 1.073607e-04 1.000107e+00
9.976038e+00 7.309408e-03 5.264547e-05 1.000053e+00
```

- [**`exp(x)`** function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html) in *awk*
- [How to take the absolute value using awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/220588/72456)

Comment: I just found out this:

Using `exp(-1*sqrt($5*$5))` which although might be little expensive, still does the job fast enough for my KB sized files. Also, taking out the array format `${line[4]}` was a lot of relief as I kept getting stuck with the syntax with that. Using straightforward `printf` is much more elegant. Thanks for you suggestions..

It would be of great help if you could add a few lines explaining how to add the titles to each column in my created data files..

Comment: add `NR==1{ print "N         (k/(s/300.0000))         Abs(S)/E         exp(Abs(S)/E)"} NR>1{....`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
##
# use: ingest.py infile1 infile2 ... infilen

import math,re,argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('infiles', type=str, help='infile names', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

for infile in args.infiles:
    with open(infile) as in_file, open(infile+".out", "w+") as out_file:
        column_names = in_file.readline().split()
        out_file.write("N (k/(s/300.0000)) Abs(S)/E exp(Abs(S)/E)\n")
        for line in in_file.readlines():
            column_values = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
            value_dict = dict(zip(column_names,column_values))
            div = value_dict["k"]/(value_dict["s"]/300.0000)
            ABS = abs(value_dict["S"])/value_dict["E"]
            EXP = math.exp(abs(value_dict["S"])/value_dict["E"])
            out_file.write("{N} {DIV} {ABS} {EXP}\n".format(N=value_dict["N"],DIV=div,ABS=ABS, EXP=EXP))
```