# Absolute value of number

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

I have a single line of numbers separated by a space.

```
read var
sum=0
for x in $var; do ...
    #add numbers together
    $((sum += x))
done
```

I need the printed value to be an absolute number

I got one more issue I am getting. The format I am trying to get an absolute number. Nothing I am doing is working. I read that

```
abs(){ 
    number
}
```

should give me this but it doesn't seem to be working. Also if that does work where do you work that into the loop?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/220588/117549

Comment: Note that ksh93 and zsh (after `zmodload zsh/mathfunc`) have an `abs()` arithmetic function. There, `echo "$(( abs(-12) ))"` will output `12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying any number by its **sign** will generate a positive number. Or, if you will the absolute value of the number. The function for sign is very simple:

```
sign () { echo "$(( $1 < 0 ? -1 : 1 ))"; }
```

The absolute value is then:

```
echo "$(( x * $(sign "$x") ))"
```

Of course, it is a lot easier to just remove the leading negative sign (if it exist), or, for completeness, any `+` or `-` sign (if it exists) with any leading spaces:

```
echo "${x##*[+-]}"   # assuming x is an integer valid in the shell.
```

Answer (score 11):

If you've a negative integer you can treat it as a string and remove the leading dash

```
x=-5
echo ${x#-}   # "5"

x=5
echo ${x#-}   # "5"
```

Comment: This is awesome - can you explain how it works?  What does the # do?

Comment: Run `man bash` and search for `parameter#word`. You'll get the details on how to remove a matching prefix pattern from a variable's value, which in this case is the literal `-`