# Converting column of values from positive to negative

Tags: shell-script, awk, columns

I have an XYZ file, most of the Z values are positive but in fact should be negative. I am wanting to convert all positive values in column three to negative (keeping values already negative the same).

I am very new to coding and have tried a few things including:

```
 awk $3 > 0 ? -1 * $3 : $3 InputFileName.txt > OutputFileName.txt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take the absolute value using awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/220588/72456) just change the comparison operator to get apposite behavior of the abs() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with this command:

```bash
awk '{ if($3>0){ printf "%8s%8s",$1,$2 ; printf "%8s\n",$3*-1 } else printf "%8s%8s%8s\n",$1,$2,$3 }' InputFileName.txt > OutputFileName.txt
```

With `printf` through `awk` the output will be produced with the format `%8s` which specifies the field width (8 in this case). So instead of get an output like this:

```
10 20 -40
34 -4 -4
1 1 -2
```

You will get:

```
      10      20     -40
      34      -4      -4
       1       1      -2
```

If you are not interested in giving a format, you can change `%8s` to `%s`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$3>0{$3 *= -1} 1' file
```