# Modifying values in a CSV column using awk, issue with using a variable

Tags: awk

I have a CSV file composed of several columns of numeric values. I want to replace the 3rd column with `abs($3-1)`, i.e., the absolute value of the number in the third column reduced by 1.

I tried using the following command:

```
awk '{d=($3>1)?($3-1):(-$3+1); print $1 " " $2 " " $d}' file.csv
```

hoping that the variable `d` would store the correct value. However, the output I get is completely wrong. What am I doing wrong here? Sorry, I am just starting out with `awk`.

Comment: What is the column separator in the CSV? You need to use the right separator in awk. Is it a “basic” CSV or can fields be quoted? If some fields are quoted, it's hard to do it right in awk, better use Python (which has a built-in CSV library).

Comment: Generally speaking, don't just say “the output is wrong”. Post some sample input and the corresponding output.

Comment: Related: [How to take the absolute value using awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220588/how-to-take-the-absolute-value-using-awk).   Alternatively, use perl which, unlike awk, does have an `abs()` function built-in.  And a complete [CSV parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) which works for any valid CSV (including quoted with embedded commas), not just simple comma-delimited input.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$d` is the value of the `d`:th field.  The value of the variable `d` is written `d`.

Your code could be simplified (without using an extra variable) as

```c
$3 = $3 > 1 ? $3 - 1 : 1 - $3
print
```

or,

```c
$3 -= 1; if ($3 < 0) $3 = -$3
print
```

... assuming that `OFS` has the correct separator value.  Using `print` without an argument will output the current record.